# simple model dialog fails work

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src='jquery.simple.modal142.js'></script>
<script>
$('#viewwid').click(function()
{
    var scr='../displayproducts';
    $.model('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">',
        {   
            closeHTML:"",
            containerCss:
            {
                    backgroundColor:"#fff",
                    borderColor:"#fff",
                    height:450,
                    padding:0,
                    width:830
            },
            overlayClose:true
        });
}

</script>
```

I use that code snip to display a model dialog when the user clicks the button of id "viewwid". The url passed in to iframe is a cakephp view page. Nothing is shown up after I click the button, any help please ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You've put `model` instead of `modal` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your script. You forget to close click(

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src='jquery.simple.modal142.js'></script> 
<script> 
$('#viewwid').click(function() 
{ 
    var scr='../displayproducts'; 
    $.model('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', 
        {    
            closeHTML:"", 
            containerCss: 
            { 
                    backgroundColor:"#fff", 
                    borderColor:"#fff", 
                    height:450, 
                    padding:0, 
                    width:830 
            }, 
            overlayClose:true 
        }); 
} 

); //<<====
</script>
```